# React grid layout not redrawing when sidebar opens

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-grid-layout

The Grid layout grid doesn't change shape unless there is a window update, for example opening the developer tools. The state is changing in the when the sidebar opens.

This issues doesn't occur when I do no set a width property on `<GridLayout>` but then there is no width.

I have attached 3 screenshots to show the issues

1. the sidebar is closed.
   [image]
2. The sidebar opens but the grid falls underneath it.
   [image]
3. Opening the developer tools (or even moving the developer tools if their open) snaps the grid into the correct place.
   [image]

I have tried many variations including the re-sizeable grid but to no avail.

The relevant code is:

```
import RGL, { WidthProvider, Layout } from "react-grid-layout";
import "../../../../../../node_modules/react-grid-layout/css/styles.css";
const GridLayout = WidthProvider(RGL);

  const defaultProps = {
    className: "layout",
    items: 20,
    rowHeight: 30,
    onLayoutChange: function(layout: any) {},
    cols: 12,
  };

  const [layoutState, setLayoutState] = useState(defaultProps);

  const generateDOM = () => {
    return _.map(_.range(layoutState.items), (i) => (
      <div key={i} style={{ border: "2px solid red", margin: "5px" }}>
        <span className="text">{i}</span>
      </div>
    ));
  };

  const generateLayout = () => {
    const p = layoutState;
    return _.map(new Array(p.items), function(item, i) {
      const y = _.result(p, "y") || Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
      return {
        x: (i * 2) % 12,
        y: Math.floor(i / 6) * (y as number),
        w: 2,
        h: y,
        i: i.toString(),
      };
    });
  };

  const [layoutS, setLayoutS] = useState(generateLayout());

  const onLayoutChange = (layout: any) => {
    layoutState.onLayoutChange(layout);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <SidebarMetrics />
      {console.log("Drawing")}
      <GridLayout
        layout={layoutS as Layout[]}
        onLayoutChange={onLayoutChange}
        {...state}
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
      >
        {generateDOM()}
      </GridLayout>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, I had time pressure so had to move on. If you find a working solution I would love to see it for the future and I have the code base still so I can try it out. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue.
It seems that it doesn't resize the grid unless some window event happens (e.g. resizing the application window).

You should check out https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout/issues/1909

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34696359)

Comment: Sorry for being ignorant, but why not? I also had a grid and a sidebar that collapses, where if the sidebar changes size, the grid remains unchanged, but when resizing the window, it snaps into place. this includes opening devtools. I believe it should solve this issue.
On another subject, sorry for the misunderstanding. I didn't pose a different question, as this github issue was already solved when I posted the sulotion.
Would love the original author of the question to provide more code for me to test this just to make sure.